# how to aggregate multiple documents into one document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

1st document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a630d295a825ee130a8b124"),
    "name" : "xxx",
    "mobile" : NumberLong(0000000000)
}
```

2nd document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a630d665a825ee130a8b12e"),
    "state" : "Haryana",
    "mobile" : NumberLong(0000000000),
    "city" : "Safidon"
}
```

3rd Document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a630d965a825ee130a8b137"),
    "mobile" : NumberLong(0000000000),
    "state" : "Haryana",
    "pincode" : 126112
}
```

My code as:

```
db.getCollection('demodata').aggregate([
{
    "$group": {
         "_id": "$mobile",
         "components": {
              "$push": {
                  "state":"$state",
                  "name":"$name",
                  "city":"$city",
                  "pincode":"$pincode"
              }
         }
    }
    },
     {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0, "mobile": "$_id", "components": 1
        }
    },
     { "$out": "mytable" }
    ])
```

Output as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a65704d5a825ee130a8f137"),
    "components" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "xxx"
        }, 
        {
            "state" : "Haryana",
            "city" : "Safidon"
        }, 
        {
            "state" : "Haryana",
            "pincode" : 126112
        }
    ],
    "mobile" : NumberLong(0000000000)
}
```

I want aggregate on basis of mobile field

I want result as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a630d965a825ee130a8b19e"),
    "name" : "xxx",
    "mobile" : NumberLong(0000000000),
    "state" : "Haryana",
    "pincode" : 126112,
    "city" : "Safidon"
}
```

Comment: You'll be needing to use the `$group` operator. Please provide code for what you've attempted so far. StackOverflow is not a free coding service. It's expected that you attempt to solve the problem yourself, then provide your non-working solution so that we may suggest changes and help you fill in the blanks.

Comment: Which mongo db version are you on ?

Comment: <a>3.4 version</a>

Comment: @shubhamgoel, such data transformation can be performed entirely in Aggregaation Framework but only since MongoDB v 3.6. Are you able to update your db ?

Comment: @mickl i will update version of mongodb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/#exp._S_mergeObjects) in 3.6.

```
db.demodata.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$mobile",
    "data":{
      "$mergeObjects":{
        "mobile":"$mobile",
        "state":"$state",
        "name":"$name",
        "city":"$city","pincode":"$pincode"
      }
    }
  }},
  {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$data"}},
  {"$out":"mytable"}
])
```

I'll add the 3.4 edit should you need. Just let me know.

Comment: @mickl Op has out stage which will generate a new id. Why would  op want to create a new document with existing primary key object id in a new collection ? Not sure what you are referring here.